# Google Wallet Input Filed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement to set amount as Google wallet format. When user enter the amount in edittext. It will show me the amount as below. I have search a lot but did not get any solution for that. If anyone can help me.Its great help to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaQ4.png)

Comment: I have tried with three editText to show all digit in separate view. but i want all digit in same edittext.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one `EditText` and format the text to HTML as the user types it in. I am not sure how would you know when is the user punching in the cents but the code can look something like:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.length() > 1) {
                String htmlCode = doSomeMagicHereAndReturnFormattedString(editable.toString());
                Spanned spannedHtml;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    spannedHtml = Html.fromHtml(htmlCode, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                } else {
                    spannedHtml = Html.fromHtml(htmlCode);
                }
                editText.setText(spannedHtml);


            }
        }

        private String doSomeMagicHereAndReturnFormattedString(String s) {
            // You need to change this to be formatted properly
            String myHtml = "<html>" + s + "</html>";
            return myHtml;
        }

    });
```